# Why, in Yamim Noraim davening, do we discuss uprooting זדון instead of רעה?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year

There is a passage in the third bracha of Shemoneh Esrei said on Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur (at least in Nusach Ashkenaz) that reads as follows:

> ועלותה תקפץ פיה וכל הרשעה כלה כעשן תכלה כי תעביר ממשלת זדון מן הארץ
>
> And iniquity will close its mouth, and all wickedness will evaporate like smoke, when You remove evil’s domination from the earth.

The above translation follows ArtScroll. Problem is, זדון doesn’t exactly mean “evil” - the word, from the same root as the term מזיד, more accurately refers to *intentional* sins, not just sins in general.

If the intent of the paytan was as ArtScroll translates, why didn’t he use the phrase כי תעביר ממשלת **רעה**, which would indeed translate to “when You remove the dominion of evil”? And if his intention was different, then what was his intention behind this particular choice of phrase?

Comment: I think most likely it's a proper noun: the Evil Dominion (probably the Romans?). BTW in the regular Amida's blessing of Lameshumadim you have the similar expression ומלכות זדון במהרה תעקר ותשבר

Comment: @DoubleAA Not in Nusach Ashkenaz (who don’t say lameshumadim anyway). Is that Eidus HaMizrach?

Comment: It is in all Nuachaot, especially Ashkenaz. (Are you accidentally using a Christian censor's made up text instead of your ancestors'?)

Comment: @DoubleAA ArtScroll has והזדים מהרה תעקר ותשבר ותמגר ותכניע במהרה ובימינו - do you refer to that line? There, the usage makes sense - in the context of מלשינים and רשעים and, in other girsaos, מינים and apparently משומדים, talking about specifically intentional sinners seems only natural. (Why would we daven for unintentional sinners to be killed, anyway?)

Comment: Indeed the subtle change from "the Evil Kingdom" to "the evil doers" was a clever way given the context to placate the Christian **governmental** censors. (So clever it even fooled Artscroll!)

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh. Well, I think you may have the beginnings of an answer, then.

Comment: *Zadon* seems to imply something "intentional" (as in *mezid* vs. *shogeg*.) Thus, *zadon* would tend to mean "corrupt". I.e., the government intentionally does things to harm people knowing that these things are wrong. *Ra'ah* I think is more "relative". I.e., the laws they place don't help most people, but that could be due to other factors, e.g. they favor one class of people over others; they are anti-abortion. Some of the citizens would consider this "bad" or "evi"l. But they are not enacting these laws to intentionally harm the entire populace.

Comment: @DanF If we’re not going like DoubleAA’s suggestion, then I understood the phrase to be similar to the previous phrases, i.e., the future once the Satan is destroyed. “Rulership” would be slightly metaphorical and simply mean that there would be no (intentional) sinners.